# How to compile c/c++ to ms-dos .com programs?

Tags: c++, c, mingw, dos

I use Code::Blocks with GNU GCC Compiler. 
My question is: is there any way to compile c/c++ code to ms-dos 16bit (.com) executable format?
I tried to set the build options and search the compiler parameters on the net, but i couldn't find anything.

Comment: googling yields http://nullprogram.com/blog/2014/12/09/

Comment: Probably not. Maybe you need [this](https://turboc.codeplex.com/).

Comment: You need an old MS-DOS compiler. That means pre-standard.

Comment: Planning a holiday in the past?

Comment: Sorry, -1 because no research. The answer's on that blog; not going to reproduce it here! Plus, as evidently the steps required to actually do this (as compared with the "you can't" below) take up a whole blog post, this is too broad.

Comment: Unfortunately that hack described in the blog doesn't allow the use of any of the C/C++ runtime library, and there are other quirks like uninitialized static variables not being zero initialized.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly compile C and/or (an ancient dialect of) C++ to a 16-bit MS-DOS .com file. The compiler/linker you have with Code::Blocks almost certainly *can't* do that though.

In particular, at least to my knowledge, gcc has never even attempted to generate code for a 16-bit, segmented-memory environment. There was at least one port of gcc to a DOS extender ([DJGPP](http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/), but it produces .exe files, not .com and it uses a proprietary DOS extender. This originally used an ancient version of gcc, but has since been updated to a much newer version of gcc.

If you really need to generate a .com file, there are quite a few options, but all the compilers are quite old, so especially with respect to C++ the language they accept is quite limited.

### Tool chains that target(ed) MS-DOS.

<sub>Caveat: As already noted, all of these are *very* old. Generally speaking, the C they accept is reasonably conformant C89, but only for fairly small programs (both in terms of code and data size--of necessity: .com files are basically limited to a combined total of 64Kbytes of data and code). The differences between the C++ they accept and anything even sort of close to modern is much more profound (e.g., some didn't support templates *at all*). All mention of conformance here is relative to other compilers of the time; by modern standards, their conformance is uniformly terrible.</sub>

1. Microsoft: Only sold C++ compilers for MS-DOS for a fairly short time--they were somewhat late into the market, and moved out of it to compilers that produced only 32-bit Windows executables fairly early. Known more for optimization than language conformance.
2. Borland: Mirror image of Microsoft. Better conformance, poorer optimization, probably the last to abandon the MS-DOS market. Their last few compilers for MS-DOS even supported C++ templates (fairly new at the time).
3. Watcom: one of the few that's [still available](http://openwatcom.org/ftp/install/) as a free download, but without commercial support. When it was new, this was generally considered one of the best available for both conformance and optimization. It's apparently been updated (to at least some extent) relatively recently, but I haven't used a recent version so I can't really comment on those updates.
4. Metaware: Quite an expensive option at the time. I never used it, but some people I respected highly considered it the best compiler you could get. Mostly targeted embedded systems.
5. Datalight/Zortech/Symantec/Digital Mars: the other one that's [still officially available](http://digitalmars.com/download/freecompiler.html). Had a small but extremely loyal following. I tried it for a while, but never found a compelling reason to prefer it over others. Digital Mars still maintains this compiler, so it's one of the few that still gets fairly regular updates.

There were quite a few more back then as well, but these probably account for well over 90% of the market at the time.

Comment: Notes - Watcom C / C++ 10.0 supported WinMem 32 for Wndows 3.1x as a model type, one of the only tool sets to do this. Microsoft Visual C / C++ 4.1 (32 bit) included Visual C / C++ 1.52 (16 bit), but didn't include the assembler (ML.EXE). Microsoft C / C++ 8.x was the last of that series. I don't recall if MASM (ML.EXE) 6.11 was part of that tool set. It also included code view source level debuggger, programmers work bench, and quick help. To produce a .COM file, you'd normally use tiny model (or option /AT for masm).

Comment: I don't think your characterisation of DJGPP is accurate; having checked today the current version of GCC it relies upon is 9.30 which was released in March 2020. The DJGPP versions seem to have been built on the 13th of April 2020. That should get you C++17 support.

Comment: @Tommy: Strangely, when I wrote the answer in 2015, I was unaware of what would be built in 2020. Can't imagine why that would be... But I'll update accordingly.

Comment: @JerryCoffin as far as I’m aware, it’s been updated a few times over the years; no idea how far behind it was in 2015 but I suspect not that far. Can rephrase this sarcastically if that’s your preference.

Comment: … indeed, when you wrote your answer, DJGPP was offering GCC 4.8.5, which was then less than six months old. You could very easily have known about that.

Comment: @Tommy: Doing a quick check, D.J. Delorie's web site (http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/) at least seems to indicate that the most recent update at the time had happened in 2003, but I suppose it's possible I misread something (parts of it are a bit confusing, such as pages showing dates much newer than the last time they claim to have been updated, so who knows).

Comment: @JerryCoffin I checked the Zip Picker, which currently links to a gcc930b.zip which is indeed GCC 9.3.0, and then I rooted into the directory backing that up — e.g. see http://www.delorie.com/pub/djgpp/current/v2gnu/00_index.txt — which actually seems to go beyond the Zip Picker's awareness and offer GCC 12.2.0. Unbelievably. Quick text search for "GNU C++ compiler 12.2.0 for DJGPP V2" and there it is from last August.

Comment: @Tommy: You do understand that the timestamp in the zip file shows when somebody built that file on their machine, not whatever time later when it was actually posted to the web site, right?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is exe2bin.  This was a utility that came with DOS to convert .EXE format object code into the .COM format (code and data in one 64K segment).  It came with DOS and some compiliers/assemblers.

Comment: exe2bin is neither necessary (in most cases) nor sufficient for the task at hand. It's an almost-incidental step with a small number of specific tool chains.